# Java API Mail Android

Tags: java, android, email

I am trying to send an email to a user once they request one, I am using Java Mail API, and I am getting errors which I don't understand, can anyone help?

The code callas a AsyncTask class called RetrieveFeedTask, but when I try and execute the task. The catch find an error with something wrong with the doInBackground.

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception Excep;

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                MimeMessage EmailMessage = new MimeMessage(EmailSession);
                EmailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("MindTrain@gmail.com"));
                EmailMessage.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(Recipient));
                EmailMessage.setSubject(Subject);
                EmailMessage.setContent(Message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                Transport.send(EmailMessage);
            }
            catch (MessagingException Excep){
                Excep.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(Excep);
            }
            catch (Exception Excep){
                Excep.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String Results) {
            EmailLoading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Recovery Sent to Email Address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getSystemUiFlags());
            finish();
        }
    }
```

It is implemented into the click button code like this

```
RetrieveFeedTask EmailTask = new RetrieveFeedTask();
EmailTask.execute();
```

The errors are as follows

```
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at rajancorporations.myapplication.ForgotPassPopUp$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(ForgotPassPopUp.java:163)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at rajancorporations.myapplication.ForgotPassPopUp$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(ForgotPassPopUp.java:148)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at rajancorporations.myapplication.ForgotPassPopUp$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(ForgotPassPopUp.java:159)
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at rajancorporations.myapplication.ForgotPassPopUp$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(ForgotPassPopUp.java:148) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
 04-26 12:19:48.947 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-26 12:19:50.313 18523-18757/rajancorporations.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18523 SIG: 9
```